# How to configure iomega StorCenter ix2 connected to PC via RJ45 cable?

Tags: windows-7, nas

My iomega ix200 is connected to my PC (windows 7) with a RJ45 cable.

I can't make it recognized by windows.

The StorManager doesn't recognize the NAS either.

Any clues really appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

NAS devices are not build to connect them directly to your computer. You must connect your iomega storcenter via a router.